# Can we create tensorflow or tflite model for object detection without uploading our dataset images to cloud?

Tags: tensorflow, dataset, machine-learning-model, image-classification, object-detection

I need to create a custom Tensor flow lite model for object detection to integrate in an android app. But I have a constraint that the dataset images to be used is confidential and cant be uploaded anywhere over cloud. I am new to machine learning and tried to create the model with the help of tutorials online. But, everywhere, they are uploading the dataset images to either google drive or other cloud platforms. Are there any options without uploading? please help me with the necessary details and resources. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You have to decide if the model needs to be trained or just perform prediction/inference. TensorFlow Lite has the ability to do both [on-device training](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/examples/on_device_training/overview) and [on-device inference](https://www.tensorflow.org/lite/guide/inference).